# How to use preg_match_all to get different variables out of a string

Tags: php, string, preg-match-all

I want to know how to get the identifier the number1 and the number2 out of this string.

```
NAME  IDENTIFIER-NUMBER1-NUMBER2
```

example:

```
John Doe ABC-3901-11801
```

I want to get the IDENTIFIER NUMBER1 and NUMBER2 seperatly into different variables.

But the problem is that i dont always know on what position it is or if there is extra text behind it like so:

```
Blablabla ABC-3901-11801 John Doe Blablabla
```

ofc there can also be different numbers and letters:

```
XYZ-46781-28102
```

Can anybody please explain me how to find those variables in php.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We can explain this to you! Show us what you've tried and we can take it from there.

Comment: There seems to be little targetable, identifiable logic for achieving what you want. In the first string, all three words are separated by hyphens, so by what logic would the first two be captured in one var, and the latter be captured in a second var?

Comment: What did you try? use a expr looking for hyphen followed by number

Comment: `/\b(?<identifier>[a-z]{3})-(?<number1>\d+)-(?<number2>\d+)\b/i` - [Example](http://viper-7.com/5wpGaJ)

Comment: I was thinking that maybe the first thing i should do is just get the whole ID-NR1-NR2 into 1 string and then go from there;

something like preg_match_all('/(ABC|XYZ) [1-9]/'), 'something', $matches);

Comment: @user1568231 See example link in my comment

Comment: @DaveRandom
i will try that and see if i can make that work

Comment: @DaveRandom its seems that it does what i wanted, thank you..

i will report back if i run in to any other problems regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that:

- Identifier is always uppercase
- Identifier is always composed of 3 letters
- Number1 only has numbers and is always preceded by dash
- Number2 only has numbers and is always preceded by dash

This regex will work -> `'/([A-Z]{3})-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/'`

example:

```
$data = 'Blablabla ABC-3901-11801 John Doe Blablabla';
preg_match_all('/([A-Z]{3})-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/', $data, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
var_dump($matches);
```

this will output

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      0 => string 'ABC-3901-11801' (length=14)
  1 => 
    array
      0 => string 'ABC' (length=3)
  2 => 
    array
      0 => string '3901' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array
      0 => string '11801' (length=5)
```

- $matches[1] is always the identifier
- $matches[2] is always number1
- $matches[3] is always number2

EDIT:
Here's also a more generic regex:

```
/([A-Za-z]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)/
```

This only assumes that the IDENTIFIER only contains letter (in any number and in uppercase or lowercase)

this regex, for instance, works in this case

```
Blablabla abcdef-3901-11801 John Doe Blablabla
```